# How to sanitize user-provided paths in Python and Flask?

Tags: python, security, web-applications, flask, user-input

I'm using user-provided names as path components in my Python/Flask web app: for example, the user creates a project named "hello", prompting my web app to make a folder called "data/hello/" to store files that the user will upload. I am wondering how to sanitize the user provided name so that, e.g., the user can't type in "../hello" and have the folder be created in a different directory. The best pathname-based solution I can come up with is something like this:

```
import os.path
rpath = os.path.relpath(input_path)
safepath = rpath[rpath.index('../'):]
```

Is there a better way to make sure my web app doesn't access files outside of the `data` directory? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Werkzeug provides [`secure_filename`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/utils/#werkzeug.utils.secure_filename) to help with this, an example is provided in the [Flask docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/fileuploads/#a-gentle-introduction)

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename) #Sanitised here
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file',
                                    filename=filename))
```